# SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source error because of an unexpected character

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws, saaj

I'm getting the following error while trying to parse a soap request which contains the "\u0001" character in data part of the xml body:

`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap]: createEnvelope - SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source`

Without this character, the code works correctly. However the request is coming from a machine which I can't control, so I need to remove this character at the backend side but I don't know how. I tried to add an interceptor but it didn't work, because it gives the error before processing the interceptor. Do you have any idea?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm facing a similar problem